# how I can move a project from "cocos2d-x-2.2 and 3.0 alpha0 /projects" to another folder?

Tags: cocos2d-x

Now create_project.py will create a project in COCOS2DX_ROOT/projects/, but I want to move to other places.
So I try to edit " create_project.py " file, on line 52

```
context["dst_project_path"] = os.getcwd() + "/../../projects/" + context["dst_project_name"]
```

But it can't work well, The project can't find cocos2d;
I hope you can help me ;) Best regards.

Comment: How about creating the project normally and then moving it to another folder manually?

Comment: But the project can't find cocos2d file

Comment: move the cocos2d files along with your project, after all they're an intrinsic part of your project

Comment: thx, It can work, but I have to move the cocos2d to my files and modify some reference.
And I found it had not a better way to modify the file.
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/issues/2860